# SAS_STATE SPACE MODELS

Tags: sas

I hope all of you are doing well. I have a question regarding the State Space Models. As you probably know, by using these models we can compute the error variances of irregular component and level component by using one observable variable. For example, assume that we have one variable; it is price of the asser. State Space Models help us to find the level and irregular components of this variable. I use the following codes in order to compute that:

```
proc ucm data = work;
model price (price is my observable variable);
irregular plot = smooth;
level checkbreak plot = smooth;
estimate plot = residual;
forecast plot = forecasts lead = 10 alpha = 0.5;
run;
```

My problem is, I need to find the error variances of irregular and level components for each group. Above mentioned code help me to find these variances by using data of all groups. For simplicity, I explain it by using a simple data. I have the following datasheet:

```
 group         price
 A                0.5
 A                0.4
 A                0.8
 A                0.1
 B                0.3
 B                0.2
 B                0.5
```

I want to get the following datasheet:

```
 group         price          Error variances of irregular components (irr.c)            Error variances of level components
 A                0.5             0.1 (assume that er.variance  of irr.c for A is 0.1)        0.3 (assume that er.variance of lev.c for A is 0.3)
 A                0.4             0.1 (assume that er.variance  of irr.c for A is 0.1)        0.3 (assume that er.variance of lev.c for A is 0.3)
 A                0.8             0.1 (assume that er.variance  of irr.c for A is 0.1)        0.3 (assume that er.variance of lev.c for A is 0.3)
 A                0.1             0.1 (assume that er.variance  of irr.c for A is 0.1)        0.3 (assume that er.variance of lev.c for A is 0.3)
 B                0.3             0.2 (assume that er.variance  of irr.c for B is 0.2)        0.1 (assume that er.variance of lev.c for B is 0.1)
 B                0.2             0.2 (assume that er.variance  of irr.c for B is 0.2)        0.1 (assume that er.variance of lev.c for B is 0.1)
 B                0.5             0.2 (assume that er.variance  of irr.c for B is 0.2)        0.1 (assume that er.variance of lev.c for B is 0.1)
```

I hope I can explain my issue. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Use a BY statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
data work;
input group $ price;
datalines;
 A                0.5
 A                0.4
 A                0.8
 A                0.1
 B                0.3
 B                0.2
 B                0.5
 ;
run;

proc print data=work;
run;

ods trace on;

ods select ParameterEstimates;

ods output ParameterEstimates=myEstimates;

proc ucm data=work;
model price;
by group;
irregular plot=smooth;
level checkbreak plot=smooth;
estimate plot=residual;
forecast plot=forecasts lead=10 alpha=0.5;
run;

proc print data=myEstimates;
run;

proc transpose data=myEstimates(keep=group component estimate)
           out=transposedEstimates;
by group;
id component;
run;

 proc print data=transposedEstimates;
 run;

proc sql;
create table myResults as
  select a.*,
       b.irregular as IrregularComponent,
       b.level as LevelComponent
  from work as a,
       transposedEstimates as b
    where a.group=b.group;
quit;

proc print data=myResults;
run;
```